# How to pronounce the "s" in "apples" in English and American English?

Tags: pronunciation

I remember my teacher told me the "s" in "apples" should be pronounced as `/z/`, but in some American teaching programs, I heard it be pronounced as `/s/`.

Which one is correct? Does it follow the same rule in English and American English?

---

Update:

Thanks for all the comments and answers.

I heard it from this free starfall math cource: http://more2.starfall.com/m/math/addResult-tennis/load.htm

There are three questions, and the things "balls", "oranges", "apples" are counted in each question. (The order may change every time)

For my ear, the "s" in all of the three words are all sound like `/s/`, not like `/z/` (in `zip`)

Do I make a mistake?

---

Update: I just record how I read the 4 words `apples`, `oranges`, `balls`, `bus/buzz`, and uploaded it to this url: http://vocaroo.com/i/s12qqzMEwOYD . For each word, I read the `s` as `/s/` first, then `/z/` (from my understanding).

So there are 8 words:

```
1. apples /s/
2. apples /z/
3. oranges /s/
4. oranges /z/
5. balls /s/
6. balls /z/
7. bus /s/
8. buzz /z/
```

Could you tell me how do you feel?

Do you think it's `/s/` or `/z/` for my reading of `1/3/5`? Do you feel it strange the way I pronounce `/z/` in my `2/4/6`? And can you distinguish the `7` and `8` from my reading?

---

Update: Thanks so much for [stangdon's fantastic comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77075/how-to-pronounce-the-s-in-apples-in-english-and-american-english?noredirect=1#comment149273_77075) and the audio recording in that comment: http://vocaroo.com/i/s0nXNmyTOsVc

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I can't imagine it being pronounced /s/.  There is no difference between British and American English on this matter, as far as I know.  Do you have an example of one of these programs?

Comment: @stangdon thanks, I just updated the question and provided the link

Comment: Could anyone help to listen to the pronunciations of "balls", "oranges", "apples" in that game (from the link of starfall in the question), and tells me is it `/s/` or `/z/` from your ear?

Comment: I finally got to listen to the exercise.  Sorry about the delay.  Having listened to it: it sounds like /z/ to me.  When the exercise says "plus", do you hear a difference between the /s/ of "plus" or "basket" and the final sound in "apples" or "equals"?  Does your native language distinguish clearly betwee /s/ and /z/, particularly at the ends of words?  Do you find it easy to distinguish the difference between the words "bus" and "buzz"?

Comment: @stangdon Thanks very much for giving me the answer. The bad news is I just listened that again and again, and really can't distinguish what's the difference between /s/ and /z/ for `plus` and `equals`. But I find it easy to distinguish the difference between `bus` and `buzz`. The `z` in `buzz` in quite like the `z` in `zip`, but the `s` in `apples` is quite like `s` in `bus` for me :(

Comment: Just uploaded an audio of the way of my reading for the words, hope someone can help to review it, thanks in advance!

Comment: I listened to your recording, and your pronunciation of /z/ is pretty good.  If I heard you speaking, I wouldn't really remark on it.  Maybe it could be a little more strongly "voiced", a little more definitely /z/ instead of /s/, but that's all.  I think the main issue will appear when a word ending in /z/ is followed by one beginning with /s/.  I made a recording of my own to demonstrate the difference: in it, I'm saying "apple/z/, apple/s/, apple/z/, apple/s/, apple/z/ sing, apple/s/ sing."  I'm exaggerating the difference a little, but only a little: http://vocaroo.com/i/s0nXNmyTOsVc

Comment: @stangdon Oh~~ Thanks so much for listening and even recording a fantastic example for me! Now I could feel you native speakers won't pronounce `/z/` as strong as I expected, I'm so happy that my puzzle is gone. Thanks again :)

Comment: 3 and 8 are spot on, and if anything the "l" in "apples" is a far bigger issue than the "s" in your pronunciation. More L, less W - this goes for your "balls" to (hehe), and the /s/ in "bus" needs to be harsher, more like the s in "snake"

Comment: @Freewind - You're very welcome!  Glad I could help you, and thank you for making me think about an aspect of English I don't usually think about!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a tricky question, because the answer from a pure phonetic perspective doesn't match the perception of most native English speakers.  (Either British or American.)

In the phonological **perception of native English speakers,** the [three allomorphs of the plural -s suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Regular_plurals) are /s/, /z/, and /əz/.  /z/ occurs after the final /l/ of 'apples', making singular /'æpəl/ into plural /'æpəlz/.  As a native speaker of American English, I thought this was the whole story until I studied phonetics.  If you ask other native English speakers, they will most likely agree that 'apples' ends with a /z/ sound.

From a **pure phonetic perspective,** the actual pronunciation of word-final /z/ in English often has very little voicing.  This is surprising if you're expecting /z/ to be voiced and /s/ to be unvoiced.  Since word-final /z/ may have very little voicing, as an English learner you might mistake it for /s/.

In typical speech, a big phonetic difference between word-final /s/ and /z/ is in the [length of the syllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Allophones_of_vowels).  Syllables ending with /s/ or another unvoiced obstruent are pronounced with a much shorter vowel, compared to syllables ending with /z/.  In other words, native English speakers would only perceive a word like 'apples' as ending with /s/ if the pronunciation of the preceding /əl/ were very short.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, an order of magnitude better than the questioner could have expected to receive.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, it does give me more information than I expected. Could you see the link in my updated question? Thanks in advance, that's really puzzled me for many days :)

Comment: Amazing answer, this is one of the subtle things that are really hard to know even for experimented english speakers.

Comment: I would say that in British English, the /s/ sound is far more pronounced in the words mentioned in the OP and I have a hard time imagining a British person pronouncing it with a /z/ sound. This doesn't seem to match the quoted sources though, so I guess it's mostly just my perception...

Answer (score 2):

We use the -s endings:

- to make plurals (dog -> dog**s**)
- to make possessives (Decap -> Decap'**s**)
- to make the third person singular of verbs (walk -> walk**s**)

---

Apples is pronounced with /z/, not /s/ because the preceding sound is voiced.

There are some good guidelines for how to pronounce inflected 's':

#### Guidelines for pronouncing inflected -s:

**1.** Pronounce -s endings as /ɪz/ when the final sound of the main word is /s/, /z/, /ʃ/,/ʒ/, /tʃ/, or /dʒ/.

**Examples:** miss -> misses /ɪz/, watch -> watches /ɪz/, wish -> wishes /ɪz/, virus -> viruses /ɪz/.

**2.** Pronounce -s endings as /s/ when the final sound of the main word is voiceless sound (except /s/, /ʃ/, /tʃ/).

**Examples:** bat -> bats /s/, look -> looks /s/, stop -> stops /s/.

**3.** Pronounce -s endings as /z/ when the final sound of the main word is voiced (except /z/, /ʒ/, /dʒ/).

**Examples** bag -> bags /z/, word -> words /z/, cell -> cells /z/, **apple -> apples /z/**.

**4.** Pronounce -s endings as /z/ when the final sound of the main word is a vowel sound.

**Examples:** go -> goes /z/, piano -> pianos /z/, tomato -> tomatoes /z/.

---

<sup>I don't think there's any exception to it, if there is, please let me know.</sup>